# SWT: Minimizing child shells on Mac OS

Tags: java, swt

I'm having problems with the way SWT child shells behave on different operating systems. On Windows, when I click on the minimize button of a child shell, only that shell will be minimized, i.e. resized/docked in the bottom left corner of the screen (which is the preferred behavior). In Linux, child shells minimize to the taskbar (which is not really a problem). However, in Mac OS X 10.5, minimizing a child shell will cause the parent window to minimize as well (which is a problem).

Child shells are created simply by passing the parent as the constructor argument, e.g.:

```
Shell editor = new Shell(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a problem with the way SWT works as much as the way different window systems / window managers work.  If you started changing the way my OS minimized windows, I'd be pretty frustrated with your application.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I'm aware of that, but, unfortunately, it's one of my customer's requirements, so there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Hmm.  How are you creating your child shells?  Are they non-modal?  Can you make them top-level shells instead of children?

Comment: @EdwardThomson They're non-modal. Unfortunately, there are a number of reasons (I'd rather not get into) why they need to have a common parent.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed there is different window management behavior on different platforms which might not be SWT's fault - can you guarantee that `getActiveShell` always returns the common parent shell?

Another solution is simply to hide the child shells - should work the same on every platform, but might not fit in the context of your application.

Anyway, I see plenty options for replacing multiple child shells. Maybe the [`TabFolder`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TabFolder.html) or the [`ExpandBar`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ExpandBar.html) could just be right for the job? Get an overview at the [widgets page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/).

If these options are not possible, you could [contact](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/#contact) the SWT project. Maybe the developers can help you with the internal workings of the Mac OS implementation. A very radical (and from normal point of view unnecessary) step would be porting over to Swing.

Comment: Yes, getActiveShell() always returns the same common parent shell (there's only one). I've thought about simply hiding the shells instead of minimizing them, then restoring them via buttons, but I'm not sure if the customer would accept that solution.